# java.lang.NullPointerException error on accessing page linked to controller class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am running a spring mvc application with classes annotated as @controller,@service,@component and for the view layer thymeleaf is used. However on navigating to the path localhost:8080/owners no owner data is displayed.Looks like even though data is getting saved in owner object but ownerservicemap is null for no reason.

Below is the error

```
    Owner data is loaded
2019-06-26 12:39:47.237  INFO 5776 --- [  restartedMain]
.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation
unchanged
2019-06-26 12:39:50.475  INFO 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring
DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-26 12:39:50.475  INFO 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet
'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-26 12:39:50.483  INFO 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in
8 ms
2019-06-26 12:39:50.507 ERROR 5776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Request processing failed; nested exception is
java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.example.Project.controllers.OwnerController.listOwners(OwnerController.java:33)
~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
```

DataLoader class to load the data

```
@Component public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final OwnerService ownerService;

    public DataLoader()
    {
            ownerService=new OwnerServiceMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Owner owner1=new Owner();
            owner1.setId(1L);
            owner1.setFirstName("ally");
            owner1.setLastName("nilson");

            Owner sa1=ownerService.save(owner1);
    }}
```

Below is the ownercontroller class

```
@RequestMapping("/owners") @Controller public class OwnerController {

    private  OwnerService ownerservice;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerController(OwnerService ownerservice)
    {
            this.ownerservice=ownerservice;
    }

    @RequestMapping({"","/","/index","/index.html"})
    public String listOwners(Model model)
    {
            model.addAttribute("owner",ownerservice.findAll());//           System.out.println(ownerservice.findById(1L).getLastName());
            return "owner/index";
    }}
```

OwnerService interface

```
public interface OwnerService extends CrudService<Owner, Long>{

    Owner findByLastName(String lastname);}
```

AbstractmapService class

```
public abstract class AbstractMapService<T,ID> {

    protected Map<ID,T> map=new HashMap<>();

    Set<T> findAll()
    {
            return new HashSet<>(map.values());
    }

    T findById(ID id)
    {
            return map.get(id);
    }

    T save(ID id,T object)
    {
            map.put(id, object);
            return object;
    }

    void deleteById(ID id)
    {
            map.remove(id);
    }

    void delete(T object)
    {
            map.entrySet().removeIf(entry->entry.getValue().equals(object));
    }}
```

OwnerServiceMap class

```
@Service public class OwnerServiceMap extends AbstractMapService<Owner,Long>implements OwnerService{

    @Override
    public Set<Owner> findAll() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Owner findById(Long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Owner save(Owner object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.save(object.getId(),object);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Owner object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.delete(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Owner findByLastName(String lastname) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: package of service class is same as controller's? Overall , is it being picked up by Spring ? Also something does not match , in case of `@Autowired` you should get a bean not Found exception, and not a Null Pointer

Comment: @AntJavaDev  Nope package is not same. Below is the package structure : 
**com.example.Project**
-> Project1.Application

**com.example.Project.bootstrap**
Dataloader.java

**com.example.Project.Controller**
OwnerController

**com.example.Project.Model**
Owner

**com.example.Project.services**
ownerservice
crudservice
com.example.Project.services.map
  abstractservicemap
  ownerservicemap

Comment: Its working now. In the DataLoader after replacing the new in constructor with @AutoWired.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Service
public class OwnerServiceMap extends AbstractMapService<Owner,Long> implements OwnerService{ ... // }
```

To be autowired, you must register with the bean.

---

### EDIT1

You did to save another service's Map.

```java
@Component public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final OwnerService ownerService;

    public DataLoader()
    {
            ownerService=new OwnerServiceMap();
    }
    // ...
```

And here,

```java
@RequestMapping("/owners") @Controller public class OwnerController {

    private  OwnerService ownerservice;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerController(OwnerService ownerservice)
    {
            this.ownerservice=ownerservice;
    }
```

check this please.

---

### EDIT2

If you register Object to bean, container has that by singleton object.
then, Using @Autowired get singleton object from container.

NOTE : it's different with GOF's singleton.

To summarize, what you use with the new keyword like `ownerService=new OwnerServiceMap();` was to create a new instance, not to use the bean instance that you assigned to the Container. So, using the different instances, the above problem occurs.

Comment: Even with @Service it is not working. Still the same output.

Comment: Can you tell which one of them is null? : ```model``` or ```ownerservice```

Comment: ownerservice. when i do (ownerservice==null) although it does not go inside the condition but when i try to get id like System.out.println(ownerservice.findById(1L).getLastName()); it returns null.

Comment: Hey what is the edit you have given? Its same as my code.

Comment: @Ashish It's right. I just mentioned where you are wrong. If it helps, please vote.